# KVM host: Ubuntu 12.04 3.2 Kernel showing incorrect "cache size" in cpuinfo?

Tags: cache, cpu

2x Xeon E5620 .
16 Cores altogether.
/proc/cpuinfo shows cache is only @ 4096kb

According to intel this should have 12MB of "smart cache".
Doing searched for E5620 and CPUinfo shows the correct number:

```
cache size : 12288 KB
```

However mine shows this:

```
processor       : 15
v    endor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 44
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5620  @ 2.40GHz
stepping        : 2
microcode       : 0x1
cpu MHz         : 2400.104
cache size      : 4096 KB
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 11
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx         
bogomips        : 4800.20
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
```

this is under a KVM kernel as a baremetal guest.

lscpu shows this:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                16
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-15
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             16
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 44
Stepping:              2
CPU MHz:               2400.104
BogoMIPS:              4800.20
Hypervisor vendor:     KVM
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              4096K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-15
```

KVM seems to be stealing some cpu cache.  why is this?

.

Answer (score 1):

For portability/compatibility reasons, by default KVM only emulates a "standard" CPU with a subset of the available host CPU features. Apart from the reduced cache, you can also see from the `flags` that none of the SSE features, for example, are available.

To provide the full set of host CPU features to guests, add the `-cpu host` option to your KVM/QEMU command line.

> For more information, see [Tuning KVM](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Tuning_KVM)